# progression bar on asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, progress-bar

currently I am using a busy image in order to show that work is being carried out in the site that i have made through the use of asp.net, which works fine, but i would like to know if this could be done using c# so that i can run in conjunction of another class running to show that program is running

```
    $().ready(function () {    

});


    function confirmit() {
        if ($.browser.msie) {
            $('#progressBar').html('<img width="120px" height="120px" alt="Please wait...." style="display: block;" id="busyimage" src="/Charter/images/ajax-loader-circle.gif">');    
        }

    $('#busyimage').show("slow");
    $('#Confirm_btn').hide("slow");
    $('#error').text("");
    $('#aspnetForm').css('cursor', 'wait');

    //alert('radio ' + $("input[id=formatOfReport_1]:checked", '#aspnetForm').val());


    if(document.getElementById('formatOfReport_0').checked) //
    {
        window.setTimeout(hideThem, 7000); // 7 sec   
    }
    if (document.getElementById('formatOfReport_1').checked) //
    {
        window.setTimeout(hideThem, 15000); // 15 sec   
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "using C#"? Keep in mind ASP.NET uses C# (or another .NET language) to produce HTML output. So you want a HTML progress bar?

Comment: I am currently using Javascript and would like to do it tyhough the class if thats possible

Comment: "Through the class" - I'm still not sure what that means? Remember, you can't run C# on the client-side. It runs *server-side*. Are you perhaps asking how you can get a server-side event to trigger a client-side progress bar increment? If that's the case, you'll want client-side javascript to either poll the server constantly for updates, or use a WebSocket implementation like SignalR - http://www.asp.net/signalr